# get solution path at build time or runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration-files, visual-studio-2015

I have a C# solution that I would like to get the path of the solution be set to the app.config during build time. for instance. Lets say I have the solutions `c:\temp\visual studio\super fun project\super_fun_project.sln` open. I build and in one of the test projects a app setting is changed to be the full path of the solution. ie

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="fullSolutionPath" value="{setAtBuild}"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

that if I were to go to `c:\temp\visual studio\super fun project\Foobar.Tests\bin\Debug\Foobar.Tests.dll.config` it would look be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="fullSolutionPath" value="c:\temp\visual studio\super fun project\super_fun_project.sln"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

or however it needs to get formated so that when at runtime I ask for the value I indeed get the correct path. I've looked down Transformation, but I can't figure out how I would get the solution path set. Are there any other tricks to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is modify the project file and add an [MsBuild Target](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx).

The target can use a [Custom Inline Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx), a task with its source code integrated into the project file.

So to add this task:

1) unload the project (right click on project node, select "Unload Project")

2) edit the project file (right click on project node, select "Edit ")

3) add the following to the project file (for example to the end) and reload it, now when you build, the config file will be modified accordingly.

```
<Project ...>
  ...
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
      <RegexReplace FilePath="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" Input="setAtBuild" Output="$(SolutionPath)" />
    </Target>
    <UsingTask TaskName="RegexReplace" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core" >
      <ParameterGroup>
        <FilePath Required="true" />
        <Input Required="true" />
        <Output Required="true" />
      </ParameterGroup>
      <Task>
        <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
                File.WriteAllText(FilePath, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(FilePath), Input, Output));
            ]]></Code>
      </Task>
    </UsingTask>
</Project>
```

Here, I've defined Output to use a Visual Studio's [MSBuild Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx) named `SolutionPath`, but you can reuse this `RegexReplace` task and update `Input` and `Output` parameters to various needs.

Comment: I'm going to use this answer instead of the other. I changed Input to match  `{setAtBuild}` but I like that it has no external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what your use case is but you can call a homegrown batch file to do this from the post-build events of your project.

**example:** create a batch script in your project entitled **'updateconf.bat'**, ensure that it is ANSII encoded (maybe use notepad++ to write the script and confirm ansii) or you'll get an exception indicating that the file is prefixed with an illegal character when you compile your VS project and check the output.

Contents of batch script:

```
@echo off > newfile & setLocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set old="{setAtBuild}"
set new=%2
set targetBinary=%3


cd %1
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%targetBinary%.config) do (
set str=%%a
set str=!str:%old%=%new%!
>> newfile echo !str!
)

del /F /Q %targetBinary%.config
rename "newfile" "%targetBinary%.config"
```

Then add a post-build event in your project properties that calls the batch script:

```
call $(ProjectDir)\updateconf.bat "$(TargetDir)" "$(SolutionPath)" $(TargetFileName)
```

Comment: I cant wait to give this a go. The test case is that i want my unit test to dynamically load the solution file and read the projects in the solution and find all test assemblies. I didn't want to hard code path in case i put this on GitHub

Comment: @RobertSnyder - Ah okay yeah that scenario makes sense if I'm understanding you.. You're saying the **solution filename** you're substituting is actually going into your test project's config file. At runtime you're interrogating the actual solution file to get projects with say **'Test'** in their *.proj filename. In that case I believe the script will work with the way you're doing it.

Comment: I tried this out, works like a charm, and i'll accept once I verify that I don't want to use the other answer. As a side note I forgot to set to ANSII on my batch file, but I got no complaints from VS2015, and it worked just fine with UTF-8. very small annoyance that someone else might have is that the xml formatting is lost.

Comment: Alright, yup I reckon doing this via msbuild is generally a more elegant approach. Regarding your aside; in my case I initially had a BOM character (BOM+UTF8) in my file so it crashed out when running. Glad u got it working regardless.